# Couchdb 2 run on openstack

Tags: couchdb, openshift, openstack, cloud-foundry

I know there are implementations of couchdb 1.6 on openstack/openshift.  But im looking for latest v2.0

If there are non, what about cloud foundry, is there an implementation for couchdb2 on it?

if no premade implementations, can someone point me to some good instructions on how to do it.

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use couchdb in several ways:

- as CF service
- as external installation
- as application

To use it as a service you need to have a Service Broker and admin access to the Cloud Foundry installation you want to use. Admin access is necessary to add the service to CF and expose it to every CF user (or to restrict access). You can go the usual CF way and use BOSH. A good starting point could be to improve the [1.5 release](https://github.com/cf-platform-eng/couchdb-boshrelease) or the [community release](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/cf-services-contrib-release).

Since you are talking for openstack I guess you already have infrastructure access. You can run CouchDB on openstack and use it as user-provided service. You'll need to open access from CF to the CouchDB network and Couch won't be visible in the CF marketplace.

Since Couch uses HTTP/HTTPS you can push it as a regular application using Docker image and use it from other applications. This can be the fastest way, but should be used for development/testing only.